# How to periodically print to terminal from an if statement that is nested in a while loop (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I am writing a java application that will hash a series of input values repeatedly until a condition is met. I have accomplished this by nesting a series of if/else statements inside a while loop. I want to be able to print the hash rate to the terminal every 3 seconds while the application is actively hashing, and not repeatedly until the condition is met. I have tried using ExecutorService and scheduling a TimerTask but neither worked the way I wanted them to as they both kept on executing after the condition that should have stopped them was met. I know I am missing something but I don't know what ):

I've included a small snippet, feel free to ask for any information you may think is relevant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried using a TimerTask like this:

```
while(iterator) {
    if (difficulty == 1) {
        if (!hash.startsWith("0")) {
            long updatedTime = System.nanoTime();
            Nonce++;
            long deltaN = updatedTime - startTime;
            long deltaS = (deltaN / 1000000000);
            long hashRate = (Nonce / deltaS);
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Current hash rate: " + hashRate + " " + "hash/s");
                }
            }, 0, 3000);
        } else {
              System.out.println("Valid hash found! " + hash);
              iterator = false;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: What this will be when finished is essentially a cheesy 'block chain' I will be using for illustrative purposes as a teaching tool, with that in mind I have included the rest of the 'miner' method below:

```
public void miner(long index, long currentTimeMillis, long data, long Nonce, String previousBlockHash, int difficulty) throws InterruptedException {
        this.index = index;
        this.currentTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis;
        this.pszTimeStamp = pszTimeStamp;
        this.Nonce = Nonce;
        this.previousBlockHash = previousBlockHash;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
        this.data = data;
        boolean iterator = true;
        String blockHeader = (index + currentTimeMillis + data + Nonce + previousBlockHash + difficulty);
        String hash = SHA256.generateHash(blockHeader);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

        while (iterator) {
            blockHeader = (index + currentTimeMillis + data + Nonce + previousBlockHash + difficulty);
            hash = SHA256.generateHash(blockHeader);
            if (difficulty == 1) {
                if (!hash.startsWith("0")) {
                    long updatedTime = System.nanoTime();
                    Nonce++;
                    long deltaN = updatedTime - startTime;
                    long deltaS = (deltaN / 1000000000);
                    long hashRate = (Nonce / deltaS);
                    System.out.println("Current hash rate: " + hashRate
                } else {
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    System.out.println("Hash found! \n");
                    System.out.println("Mined block hash: \n" + hash);
                }
            } else if (difficulty == 2) {

            ...........
```

All of the parameters the 'miner' method takes are passed to it by a launching class which includes the main function. My goal is to be able to print the hash rate while it searches for a 'valid' hash every few seconds instead of it printing thousands of times per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few suggestions:

- I personally would prefer using `break` inside a `while(true)` loop instead of of a loop variable. I feel that it makes the code more readable;
- You are re declaring the `Timer` inside the loop, which means that a new timer is created each iteration of the loop. You need to create the timer once, outside the loop.

The `Timer` variable needs to be final to allow you to call `timer.cancel()` inside the run function of the TimerTask. If you plan on terminating the timer outside the run function, then the `Timer` variable need not be final.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Test{
    static double Nonce;

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{
        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            public void run(){
                //calcualte hashRate by any formula
                double hashRate = Nonce/100.0;

                //check if the timer needs to continue, else call timer.cancel()

                System.out.println(hashRate);
            }
        }, 0, 500);

        while(true){
            Thread.sleep(100);
            Nonce++;

            if(Nonce == 100){
                timer.cancel(); //or terminate the timer outside the loop
                break;
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need any help.

---

Edit:

A few things I have noticed:

- The class variable `Nonce` cannot be static, otherwise it will be shared amongst all instances of the class.
- The name of the variable cannot be `Nonce` in the function declaration, otherwise the local copy will be used whenever you use `Nonce` within the miner function.
- If you do not calculate the hashRate directly, then deltaS can be zero, which may lead to a divide by 0 error.

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

```java
public class ChainBuilder extends MainChain {

    private long index;
    private long currentTimeMillis;
    private long data;
    private int difficulty;
    private String pszTimeStamp;
    private String previousBlockHash;
    private String currentHash;
    private String genesisHash;

    public long Nonce; //Nonce cannot be be static, otherwise it will cause issues if more than one object is created.
    public static long startTime;

.......
public void miner(long index, long currentTimeMillis, long data, long _Nonce /*You cannot use Nonce here*/, String previousBlockHash, int difficulty) throws InterruptedException {
        this.index = index;
        this.currentTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis;
        this.pszTimeStamp = pszTimeStamp;
        this.Nonce = _Nonce; /*In this scope, Nonce refers to the local variable, and this.Nonce refers to the class variable. 
                            If you use Nonce in this scope, then the class variable will not be changed.*/
        this.previousBlockHash = previousBlockHash;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
        this.data = data;
        boolean iterator = true;
        String blockHeader = (index + currentTimeMillis + data + Nonce + previousBlockHash + difficulty);
        String hash = SHA256.generateHash(blockHeader);
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long endTime = System.nanoTime();
                long deltaN = endTime - startTime;
                //long deltaS = (deltaN / 1_000_000_000);
                long hashRate = (1_000_000_000 * Nonce / deltaN); /*calculate the hashRate directly, because if deltaN < 1_000_000_000, 
                                                                then deltaS will be 0, giving a divide by zero error.*/
                System.out.println("Current hash rate: " + hashRate + " " + "hash/s");
            }
        }, 0, 3000);
        while (iterator) {
            blockHeader = (index + currentTimeMillis + data + Nonce + previousBlockHash + difficulty);
            hash = SHA256.generateHash(blockHeader);
            if (difficulty == 1) {

                if (!hash.startsWith("0")) {
                    Nonce++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Hash found!");
                    timer.cancel();
.......
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. The hash rate is being calculated, not incremented. The nonce value is one of the values that is being used to create the hash, and is the only thing being incremented. What this will be when finished is essentially a cheesy 'block chain' I will use for illustrative purposes as a teaching tool. I will update my post to include more of the method so that maybe it will make more sense what is going on and what I would like to achieve.

Comment: I have updated the code. Please let me know if this is what you need. You can let `hashRate` be a global (class) variable, and have all the if statements update it, then print out the `hashRate` whenever needed. @apt-getschwifty

Comment: We can't break from the loop using the nonce value since it will be different every time. It starts at 0 and is incremented until a hash is found that starts with the correct number of zeros, which sometimes takes millions or even billions of iterations. Thank you for taking time to take a look though. This should be a simple task, it's driving me nuts that I can't figure it out haha.

Comment: I included the Nonce value only as an example. There has be some condition that, when met, results in the termination of the loop. Just call `timer.cancel()` whenever you terminate the loop, and the timer will stop printing to the screen.

Comment: Well that's kind of my issue, the condition that terminates the loop is the discovery of a hash that starts with the correct number of zeros.. So I can't seem to figure out how to break the loop and stop the timer with the same condition without the timer being inside of it, which like you said (and as I had a sneaking suspicion of) recreates the timer.. ):

Comment: If you need to stop printing the hash once the loop exits, just call `timer.cancel()` immediately after the loop body. Eg: `while(condition){...//code} timer.cancel();`

Comment: I guess I am just confused. How can have the timer (who's purpose is to print the hash rate at a specified interval) outside of the while loop if the data it's printing is dependent on values from inside the while loop? The change in nano time (deltaN) is calculated using a reference start time outside of the loop (startTime) and an updated time inside the loop (updatedTime), which is then divided by a billion to get deltaS (change in seconds) which is the value used to calculate the hash rate (Nonce / deltaS).. could I make the variables static instead of local to achieve this?

Comment: I credited your answer as your directives got me headed on the right track towards my desired outcome, so thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. About the timer: The timer starts a separate thread that only runs the code specified in the run method after a fixed interval. The code in the run method reads the value of the `Nonce` variable, calculates the hashes per second, and then prints the value, independent of the while loop. You do not need to calculate the hashRate in the while loop, you can do it in the run method, and have fewer class variables. Please let me know if you need any help.

Comment: There are a few errors in your code. I have updated my answer, please take a look and let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: I like your method for calculating the hash rate directly using Nano time, and I ran into the divide by 0 error haha, that's why I have that little sleep before the while loop. I thought declaring nonce static would cause an issue too, but it is actually working perfectly. I will look into narrowing access modifiers and things once I have all the core functionality ironed out. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You are welcome . Also, declaring `Nonce` static will not result in any errors as long as you use only one instance of the object, but I strongly suggest looking into this because it can lead to some very, very hard to pin down errors. I once had to rewrite a whole module because I accidentally declared a variable static.

Comment: Hahahaha yeah fun stuff with Java's nazi access modifiers. Luckily the way it's written each time the main method calls the miner method nonce is reinitialized to zero so it can start being incremented.

Comment: Hate to be pedantic here, but just so you know, static is not an access modifier in Java. Also, a static variable is shared amongst all instances of a class, so if you call the miner method on one object, then it will set the value of Nonce to 0 in all objects of the class. I wish you luck in implementing the rest of the blockchain. May I also suggest that you put it up on GitHub? I personally don't know a lot about blockchains, but would like to contribute.

Comment: Haha no worries, I am learning so I am happy to be corrected. The way it's written the value of the nonce is applied immediately to the chain (contained within the block it was found for) and is used for checking the validity of the hash along with the rest of the values of the block i.e. time, previous hash etc. All the values are stored in an array list and serialized after validation to a file so they can be read in when the app is started. I am gonna put it up on github, I will leave a comment for you on here when I do so you can check it out. Maybe we can exchange emails too.

Comment: I just started this project this weekend because it seemed like it would be fun and challenging. It is effectively a private block chain at this point though, as there's no http server/json implementation or any network protocol implementation. But it's pretty neat still!

Comment: I have always wanted to learn more about the blockchain protocol, especially after the Bitcoin hype, but never found the time. This seems to be a great opportunity, and I will be happy to contribute to the project once you put it up on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so what worked for me was declaring the relevant variables static, putting the start of the timer before loop, and cancelling upon the discovery of a valid hash, like so:

```
public class ChainBuilder extends MainChain {

    private long index;
    private long currentTimeMillis;
    private long data;
    private int difficulty;
    private String pszTimeStamp;
    private String previousBlockHash;
    private String currentHash;
    private String genesisHash;
    public static long deltaS;
    public static long deltaN;
    public static long Nonce;
    public static long startTime;
    public static long endTime;
    public static long hashRate;
.......
public void miner(long index, long currentTimeMillis, long data, long Nonce, String previousBlockHash, int difficulty) throws InterruptedException {
        this.index = index;
        this.currentTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis;
        this.pszTimeStamp = pszTimeStamp;
        this.Nonce = Nonce;
        this.previousBlockHash = previousBlockHash;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
        this.data = data;
        boolean iterator = true;
        String blockHeader = (index + currentTimeMillis + data + Nonce + previousBlockHash + difficulty);
        String hash = SHA256.generateHash(blockHeader);
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Current hash rate: " + hashRate + " " + "hash/s");
            }
        }, 0, 3000);
        while (iterator) {
            blockHeader = (index + currentTimeMillis + data + Nonce + previousBlockHash + difficulty);
            hash = SHA256.generateHash(blockHeader);
            if (difficulty == 1) {

                if (!hash.startsWith("0")) {
                    endTime = System.nanoTime();
                    Nonce++;
                    deltaN = endTime - startTime;
                    deltaS = (deltaN / 1000000000);
                    hashRate = (Nonce / deltaS);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Hash found!");
                    timer.cancel();
.......
```